# SMSS (SQL Server Management Studio) debugger keeps going to "Create Function"

Tags: sql-server

I am using SMSS 17.3

SMSS (SQL Server Management Studio) debugger keeps going to "Create Function"

I have a function

originally

```
CREATE FUNCTION testaaa()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 44
END;
```

Then I wanted to amend it so I changed it to ALTER function and I made it return 45.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[testaaa]()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 45
END;
```

When I execute a call, I get 45, so the function has been altered.

[image]

Say I set a breakpoint and choose debug

[image]

It jumps into CREATE FUNCTION

[image]

If I ever add any code to ALTER function, I can't see how to step through it, since the debugger keeps calling create function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After create/Alter the function, close all the window you used for create or alter the function.  Then open new window and execute your statement and debug, now debugger will open your latest script.

**Note added by barlop**
It still opens a CREATE FUNCTION, though the latest one. (which is OK though worth mentioning).

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried that.  I think it still opens a CREATE FUNCTION, though the latest one. (which is OK though worth mentioning). Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, it will open as CRETAE FUNCTION.